# Why is my title so squeezed?

Tags: titles, fontsize, line-spacing

I print the title of my document like this:

```
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \vspace*{\fill}
  {\huge\bfseries \getTitle}

  \vspace*{\fill}
  {\huge\bfseries \getTitleGer}
\end{titlepage}
```

And the title is defined like this:

```
  \newcommand*{\getTitle}{Unified Visualization for Execution Architectures of Big Data Frameworks}
  \newcommand*{\getTitleGer}{Einheitliche Visualisierung der Ausf\"uhrungsarchitekturen von Big Data Frameworks}
```

Strangely enough LaTeX prints it like this.
Why this strange squeezing, when the other title's line break is correctly done.
When I change the input of the first title to anything else it correctly breaks the line, it seems to not do so for EXACTLY the title that I need (of course...)

[image]

After adding \par to each title it looks like this, with a too big spacing:

[image]

I want it to look like with the first image but with consistent spacing.

Comment: You need to add a `\par` at the end: `{\huge\bfseries \getTitle\par}` and `{\huge\bfseries \getTitleGer\par}`.

Comment: Yeah works, but now the gap is huge and a bit unaesthetic... See the edit...

Comment: @J.Doe Instead of `\huge` you could use `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont` to set the size and baselineskip independently to whatever you want. Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the lack of the `\par`, the font size is changed, but the line spacing remains that of the outside text (`10` to `12 pt`), so instead of using the correct line spacing (`\baselineskip`), TeX resorts to the `\lineskip`, which is the space between the base of one line to the top of the next. In both cases the `\lineskip` is used, but the in the German title, the base of the line is lowered by the `g`, thus the line spacing looks off.

You can, instead of the `\huge` command, which sets the line spacing proportional to the font size, directly use the `\fontsize` command, as samcarter mentioned in her comment.

With a little hand-tuning this setting looks like the one you want:

[image]

Produced with:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcommand*{\getTitle}{Unified Visualization for Execution Architectures of Big Data Frameworks}
\newcommand*{\getTitleGer}{Einheitliche Visualisierung der Ausf\"uhrungsarchitekturen von Big Data Frameworks}

\makeatletter
\centering
{\fontsize{\@xxpt}{19.5}\selectfont \bfseries \getTitle\par}

\vspace{2cm}
{\fontsize{\@xxpt}{19.5}\selectfont \bfseries \getTitleGer \par}

\end{document}
```

Notes:

- The definition of `\huge` uses `\fontsize{\@xxpt}{25}`. I changed the `25` to `19.5` by trial and error.
- The `\@xxpt` command is defined as `20.74`, so you can replace it by that value.
- This setting considers a font size configuration of `10pt`. If you are using another size you have to change the values to match the corresponding `\huge` command.

Comment: How did you know it's German ;) Works, Thanks a ton you saved my thesis!

Comment: I wasn't sure, but `Ausführungsarchitekturen` gave me a good clue ;) Be careful, though! People in this site have already got stuck in a ["never-ending thesis writing endeavour"](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Paulo_Cereda/publication/329058854_Macros_como_mecanismos_de_abstracao_em_transformacoes_textuais/links/5bf3bda8299bf1124fdf9f4e/Macros-como-mecanismos-de-abstracao-em-transformacoes-textuais.pdf) (final paragraph of page 9). Try not to get caught as well :)

Comment: Fair enough! No I am finished with it, and now focus solely on LaTeX edits... ;)